# How could I store a select option in a variable beyond just submittable params to be stored in/used in a helper method in a rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Trying to figure out the logic to how I can pull the group_id selected from the join group form and store it into a helper method similar to current_user method. I have to adhere to strict has_many through and am stumped on how I would get the correct group_id to match each post to display with each method or even sort posts by group_id at the moment. Some direction would be greatly appreciated...

Join group form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-4">
      <h2 class="text-center">Join a Group</h2>
        <%= bootstrap_form_for @membership do |f| %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :permission, value: 'student' %>

            <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(Group.all, 'id', 'name')%>
            <%= f.select  :group_id, options %>

           <%= f.submit "Join", class: 'form-control' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
```

my database schema

```
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "permission", default: "student", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "membership_id"
    t.integer "group_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "username", default: "", null: false
    t.string "first_name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "last_name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

the post form

```
<div class="new_post">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
  <%= bootstrap_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :membership_id, value: 4 %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br/>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these forms on the same view or is the user directed to a different page when they submit the join group form? If it redirects, you could grab the group id from the params and memoize for a helper method. Other wise, if they are on the same page, you're probably gonna need some JS

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I had to do this without the use of JS. I ended up passing the group id via a 'link_to' into a params and setting a session variable that changes each time the user switches to a different group.